# Quartz scheduler Failed to obtain DB connection from data source

Tags: java, mysql, quartz

I'm trying to setup quartz scheduler with mysql database and I'm getting the below exception. Can someone help me on this, Please.

I have included the below jars:

c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar
jta-1.1.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar
quartz-2.2.1.jar
quartz-jobs-2.2.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar
slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar

```
[LMWJobScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] ERROR org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger - An error occurred while scanning for the next triggers to fire.
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'myDS': java.sql.SQLException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ java.beans.IntrospectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException [lastAcquisitionFailureDefaultUser] ] has been closed() -- you can no longer use it. [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ java.beans.IntrospectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException [lastAcquisitionFailureDefaultUser] ] has been closed() -- you can no longer use it.]
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:778)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreTX.java:71)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3784)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTriggers(JobStoreSupport.java:2756)
at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:272)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ java.beans.IntrospectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException [lastAcquisitionFailureDefaultUser] ] has been closed() -- you can no longer use it.
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.assertCpds(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:447)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getPoolManager(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:459)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
at org.quartz.utils.PoolingConnectionProvider.getConnection(PoolingConnectionProvider.java:247)
at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.getConnection(DBConnectionManager.java:108)
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:775)
... 4 more
```

This is the quartz.properties

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: JobScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId: AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck: true

org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class =org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = quartz-config.xml
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.wrapInUserTransaction = false

org.quartz.threadPool.class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 20
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5

org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=myDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user: root
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password: password
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections: 5
```

quartz-config.xml

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_2_0.xsd"
                     version="2.0">

```
<schedule>
    <job>
        <name>Hello</name>
        <group>HelloGroup</group>

        <description>The job description</description>
        <job-class>HelloJob</job-class>
    </job>       
    <trigger>
        <cron>
            <name>hello-trigger</name>
            <group>Hello_Group</group>
            <job-name>Hello</job-name>

            <job-group>HelloGroup</job-group>
            <cron-expression>0/30 0/1 * 1/1 * ?</cron-expression>

        </cron>
    </trigger>        
</schedule>
```

Main class

```
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

  public class QuartzTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory
        Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

        // and start it off
        scheduler.start();

        scheduler.shutdown();

    } catch (SchedulerException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Job class

```
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;

public class HelloJob implements Job {
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context){
        System.out.println("Hello World !!!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for the issue.

```
scheduler.shutdown();
```

This statement shutdown the quartz server before the job trigger and the connection is no more available.

Answer (score 0):

Check your DB version. If the DB version is 8+, you should use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. Then check dolphinscheduler`s pom.XML. Is there scope at mysql-connector dependencies? If there is a scope test, annotate it.